# Specify Quality for Youtube Chromeless Player not working?

Tags: youtube-javascript-api

I'm developing with the Youtube Chromeless player.
My player size is 400 x 225px.

By default, Youtube sets videos quality at a "small" level with these dimensions.
Yet, as videos with "small" quality look ugly, I would like to upgrade them to the "medium" quality level.

This is my code:

```
ytplayer.loadVideoById(youtube_id, start, "medium");
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to work... When I do some inspection on my console:

```
ytplayer.getPlaybackQuality();
"small"
```

Is someone experiencing the same issues with the Youtube API? If not, how do you specify the quality of your Youtube videos?

**====== Edit =======**

I've realized that once the video has started, the setPlaybackQuality function works. Therefore, I tried the hack below. It's perfectly working but would rather find another solution...

```
ytplayer.loadVideoById(YOUTUBE_ID, START);
setTimeout(function(){
    // If medium quality available
    if(ytplayer.getAvailableQualityLevels().indexOf("medium") != -1){
        ytplayer.setPlaybackQuality("medium");
    }
},1000)
```

Thanks a lot,

Dam

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally managed to solve this problem.

I did a different hack but way less ugly. Here it is:

```
function onYoutubePlayerReady(playerId){
    [...]

    // Add event listener to monitor quality
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onPlaybackQualityChange","onQualityChange");

    // Triggers the video
    ytplayer.loadVideoById(youtube_id, start, "medium");

    [...]

}
```

And this is the event listener in charge of forcing the videos quality to "medium"

```
function onQualityChange(qualityState){
    if(qualityState != "medium" && ytplayer.getAvailableQualityLevels().indexOf("medium") != -1){
        ytplayer.setPlaybackQuality("medium");
    }
}
```

Now works like a charm.

If you have any suggestion, please let me know.